# 3.3V to 5V driver (push-pull) output too low

Tags: driver, buffer, texas-instruments, push-pull

I was recently testing using [SN74LVC1G17DCKR](https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=10&gotoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fsn74lvc1g17) and was having trouble getting the output voltage to reach close to Vcc as per the datasheet. Vcc input is 5 V. My input was 3.27 V and I was getting around 3.1 V output.

I am currently not loading the output of the buffer with the exception of the multimeter and am still getting an output voltage of 3.1 V for an input 3.2 V.

As per the datasheet , Vt+ (worst case max.) can be between 2.78 V and 3.3 (for Vcc of 4.5 - 5.5 V) which puts the Vt+ around 3 for 5 V input. And, as long as load current is within 0.1 mA I should be getting and output high of Vcc-0.1 V.

What could I be doing wrong?

I have attached schematics. First image is what is eventually going to be connected to the output of the buffer.
Second image is shows my test setup of the buffer

[image: Intended and eventual circuit]
[image: Schematic of test setup]
[image: Test setup]

Comment: What does your 5 V measure?

Comment: It measures around 5.012V . I am using an LM1117 to power the chip from a 12V input